# If I need to restrict access to certain databases?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, access-control

So I've just created a MySQL server. I also created some users only having specific access to certain databases, but do I need to restrict access to default databases to the users I've created?
If so, how? Should I just create a role to try to restrict this access?

I have been using this site as a reference:
https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mysql-reference-manual/0596002653/ch04s02.html

Comment: *do I need to restrict access to default databases to the users I've created?* What "default databases" you're asking about? The database which is set for user as current during connect?

Comment: @Akina the information_schema, mysql, performance_schema, and sys databases

Comment: Common users do not need any access to `sys` and `performance_schema`. May have RO access to `mysql`, tables `func`, relative to help and timezone, and maybe `db`. And RO access to a lot of tables in `information_schema`.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should start by running [mysql_secure_installation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-secure-installation.html) on any mysql production database servers to ensure the minimum security measures are in place. You shouldn't need additional restrictions on general users after this.

Answer (score 0):

An application will have one or more `DATABASES`.

If the application provides an interface (API) between users and the databases, then provide a small number of pseudo users with explicit permissions granted only to the relevant tables of the app.  Something like this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON myapp.* TO app@...
```

If you are allowing users to login *directly* to MySQL, you are asking for many nightmares.  Still, limited grants like the above one give you some protection.